# Crontab for shellscript

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am using crontab for running shell script in crontab.
but I am not able to get the output.

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
*  *    * * *   omdev   /home/omdev/Desktop/Log4jTesting/cronscript.sh
*  *    * * *   omdev   echo "Hello"
```

Last two cronjob are not working.

```
*  *    * * *   omdev   /home/omdev/Desktop/Log4jTesting/cronscript.sh
*  *    * * *   omdev   echo "Hello"
```

For additional info
1. I have restarted service after adding them.
2. I have tried running script without cronjob it is working absolutely fine.
3. Shell Script is executable.

Comment: Why are you using a system crontab (specifying the user) rather than the `crontab` command?

Comment: Do you mean I should write both in different crontab ?

Comment: I mean that you should use the `crontab` command to maintain the crontab for each user account unless you have a very good reason to mess around with system crontabs.

Comment: Thanks @Keith Thompson I have resolved it.

Comment: Consider posting an answer so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I was using systemcron.
thanks (@keith Thompson) for reminding me the mistake.
I must use crontab in this way.

Step 1:

```
Crontab -n
```

Enter the cronjob here. This will make job assigned by the user.

Step 2:

```
Crontab -l
```

To see list of cronjob given by us. We can also use -u option to see the list specific to user.

```
crontab -l -u <User's Name>
```